# How do I write a createCriteria in grails which pull only few columns from the table instead of all columns?

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

How do I write a createCriteria in grails which pull only few columns from the table instead of all columns?

I have a table called Ads. I want to retrieve only columns "Title" , "Price" and "Photo".

```
def c = Classified.createCriteria()
    def records = c.list {
            eq('publish_date', '2014-06-06')
        }
        maxResults(8)
    }
```

Above query retrieves all the records. How to restrict to only few columns?

Comment: use `projections`..,. http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def records = Classified.withCriteria {
    eq('publish_date', '2014-06-06')

    projections {
        property('title')
        property('price')
        property('photo')
    }        
    maxResults(8)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use projections to achieve this - at the simplest

```
projections {
    property('title')
    property('price')
    property('photo')
}
```

would cause `c.list` to return a list of three-element lists, where `records[n][0]` is the title, `records[n][1]` is the price etc.  If you want to be able to access the properties by name rather than by number then you need to assign aliases and use a result transformer

```
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer

def c = Classified.createCriteria()
def records = c.list {
    eq('publish_date', '2014-06-06')
    maxResults(8)
    projections {
        // first param is the property name, second is the alias definition -
        // typically you'd leave them the same but here I make them different
        // for demonstration purposes
        property('title', 'ttl')
        property('price', 'cost')
        property('photo', 'picture')
    }
    resultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
}
```

Now `records` will be a list of maps rather than a list of lists, and you can access the projected properties by alias name - `records[n].ttl`, `records[n].cost`, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about the ability to transform the results into a list of maps, will make for much more readable code +1